# Regex to define right text patterns with every part, that could be unnecessary

Tags: regex

I need to validate the strings by regex. This string have a following form:

> 0M 1d 2h 3m

Every part of this string is unnecessary, but the letters should be written in alphabetical order which is provided here: M, d, h, m.

So what regex should I implement to match all these patterns here :

> 1M 2d 3h 4m
>
> 5M 6d
>
> 7d 8h
>
> 9h 10m
>
> 11M
>
> 12d
>
> 13h
>
> 14m

Also, I should mention that there could be digits from 0-100 in required string patterns

Comment: Yes, yes. I'll fix it. My bad

Comment: Can your patterns be like `1M 3h` or `1M 4m` i.e middle terms skipped ?

Comment: Yes, they should be skipped if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can have middle terms skipped in your pattern for eg. `1M 3h` or `1M 4m`  then you can use it:

```
"^((100|[0-9]{1,2})M\s*)?((100|[0-9]{1,2})d\s*)?((100|[0-9]{1,2})h\s*)?((100|[0-9]{1,2})m\s*)?$"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `?` quantifier to look for 0-1 matches for each group. Put each group in the right order, and the regex will not return anything that is in the wrong order. Include the beginning of string `^` and end of string `$` so you do not get a result for each combination of groups. This will also result true for an empty string, so watch out of that.

`^(\d{1,2}M\s*)?(\d{1,2}d\s*)?(\d{1,2}h\s*)?(\d{1,2}m)?$`

Comment: I've forgot to mention that there could be any digit from 1 to 100 instead of those random digits in my question. So, i suppose the answer should be something like this?

^((?:100|[1-9]?[0-9])M\s*)?((?:100|[1-9]?[0-9])d\s*)?((?:100|[1-9]?[0-9])h\s*)?((?:100|[1-9]?[0-9])m)?$

Comment: Depending on your requirements, I would do ((100)|(\d{1,2})M\s*)?... because some people like to left pad their numbers with 0s. Also, I don't think you need those ?: you added.